# ld can't find libGL (16.04LTS x64 + Nvidia driver)

Tags: nvidia, opengl, libraries, g++, update-alternatives

I used `update-alternatives` to select **nvidia-367** as the provider for opengl.

I ran ldconfig

I checked that all the symlinks are valid and pointing to the correct folder·

```
root@laptop:/etc/ld.so.conf.d# ls -halt
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  41 sep.   2 18:59 i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf -> /etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_egl_conf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  40 sep.   2 18:59 i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf -> /etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  43 sep.   2 18:59 x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  42 sep.   2 18:59 x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf

root@laptop:/etc/alternatives# cat x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf 
/usr/lib/nvidia-367
/usr/lib32/nvidia-367
```

but still when I pass `-Wl,--verbose` to g++ during build of my project, I get the following:

```
[...]
attempt to open /home/lennart/Qt/5.7/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libGL.so failed
attempt to open /home/lennart/Qt/5.7/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libGL.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libGL.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libGL.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libGL.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libGL.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libGL.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libGL.a failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.a failed
attempt to open /lib/../lib/libGL.so failed
attempt to open /lib/../lib/libGL.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/../lib/libGL.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/../lib/libGL.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../libGL.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../libGL.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //lib64/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //lib64/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //lib/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //lib/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libGL.a failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libGL.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libGL.a failed
[...]
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As you see, there is no mention of the nvidia-367 folder anywhere, even if ld config is clearly configured to look at it.

What gives?

Comment: Do you have the `libgl1-mesa-dev` package installed? AFAIK ldconfig determines runtime dependencies - you still need the appropriate -dev package for the link-time dependencies

Comment: yes I do have that package installed